# Store output of sed into a variable

Tags: bash

I want to store the second line of my file into a variable, so I am doing this:

```
sed -n '2p' myfile
```

I wish to store the output of the `sed` command into a variable named `line`.

What is the correct syntax to do this?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Use [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) like this:

```
line=$(sed -n '2p' myfile)
echo "$line"
```

Also note that there is no space around the `=` sign.

Comment: This also hangs....I'm starting to think that I don't fully understand the issue I'm having.

Comment: Are you using the exact command that I said?

Comment: of course....I did an update and now it works. Thank you all very much

Answer (score 35):

In general,

```
variable=$(command)
```

or

```
variable=`command`
```

The latter one is the old syntax, prefer `$(command)`.

Note: `variable = ....` means execute the command `variable` with the first argument `=`, the second `....`

Comment: I've tried this...it isn't working line = `sed -n '2p' myfile` just hangs...

Comment: the second way worked for me, thank you @KarolyHorvath :)

Answer (score 8):

To store the third line into a variable, use below syntax:

```
variable=`echo "$1" | sed '3q;d' urfile`
```

To store the changed line into a variable, use below syntax:
variable=`echo 'overflow' | sed -e "s/over/"OVER"/g"`
output:OVERflow

Answer (score -1):

```
line=`sed -n 2p myfile`
echo $line
```

Comment: I've fixed the formatting of your answer.