# How to use sed to extract a string

Tags: shell, sed

I need to extract a number from the output of a command: `cmd`. The output is `type: 1000`
So my question is how to execute the command, store its output in a variable and extract 1000 in a shell script. Also how do you store the extracted string in a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the output is rigidly restricted to "type: " followed by a number, you can just use `cut`.

```
var=$(echo 'type: 1000' | cut -f 2 -d ' ')
```

Obviously you'll have to pipe the output of your command to `cut`, I'm using `echo` as a demo.

In addition, I'd use `grep` and then `cut` if the string you are searching is more complex. If we assume there can be all kind of numbers in the text, but only one occurrence of "type: " followed by a number, you can use the command:

```
>> var=$(echo "hello 12 type: 1000 foo 1001" | grep -oE "type: [0-9]+" | cut -f 2 -d ' ')
>> echo $var
1000
```

Comment: Got what you mean. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged your question as `sed` but your question description does not restrict other tools, so here's a solution using `awk`.

```
output = `cmd | awk -F':' '/type: [0-9]+/{print $2}'`
```

Alternatively, you can use the newer `$( )` syntax. Some find the newer syntax preferable and it can be conveniently nested, without the need for escaping backtics.

```
output = $(cmd | awk -F':' '/type: [0-9]+/{print $2}')
```

Comment: type: 1000 is only one of the many lines from the output. So I think I want to match the exact pattern, and then extract the string following it. Thanks.

Comment: Why not using just using `awk`? `cmd | awk '/type : [0-9]+/ {print $3;exit}`. `grep` and especially `egrep` isn't required. However, I would still use `sed`

Comment: You should not use old and outdated back ticks, use parentheses `$(code)` like this `output=$(cmd | awk -F':' '/type: [0-9]+/{print $2}')`

Comment: @jotne the op did not mention which shell he is using and I believe the old style is more portable across shells.  Please correct if I'm mistaken.

Comment: As far as I have found and what other has written, you need a very old and obscure system to not have parentheses. If you are in doubt, post both and say that its preferable to use parentheses.  (do a google search on it)

Comment: @Jotne, I have updated it to include both, but note that the link inside the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4708569/391161) does not say one is deprecated in favor of the other.

Comment: The syntax in this answer is wrong; you can't have whitespace on either side of the `=` in a shell script variabde assignment.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical use case for `grep`:

```
output=$(cmd | grep -o '[0-9]\+')
```

You can write the output of a command or even a pipeline of commands into a shell variable using so called [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html):

```
variable=$(cmd);
```

---

In comments it appeared that the output of `cmd` contains more lines than the `type : 1000`. In this case I would suggest `sed`:

```
output=$(cmd | sed -n 's/type : \([0-9]\+\)/\1/p;q')
```

Comment: type: 1000 is only one of the many lines from the output. So I think I want to match the exact patter, and then extract the string following it. Thanks.

Comment: ah, ok.. then I would use `sed`... gimme a sec. Btw, you see that nobody got this detail. You should enhance your question.

Comment: right, I got to know how to do it with cut. Thanks a lot anyway

Comment: ??? sorry, this makes `0` sense! how could cut handle mutltiple lines in output? Your are accepting  and upvoting actually the worst answers

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered in pieces here before, it would be something like this:

```
line=$(sed -n '2p' myfile)
echo "$line"


if [ `echo $line || grep 'type: 1000' ` ] then;
  echo "It's there!";
fi;
```

[Store output of sed into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749128/store-output-from-sed-into-a-variable)

[String contains in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/string-contains-in-bash)

EDIT: sed is very limited, you would need to use bash, perl or awk for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the | operator to send the output of one command to another, like so:

```
echo " 1\n 2\n 3\n" | grep "2"
```

This sends the string " 1\n 2\n 3\n" to the grep command, which will search for the line containing 2. It sound like you might want to do something like:

```
cmd | grep "type"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plain sed solution that uses a regualar expression to find the number in your string:

```
cmd | sed 's/^.*type: \([0-9]\+\)/\1/g'
```

- `^` means from the start
- `.*` can be any character (also none)
- `\([0-9]\+\)` are numbers (minimum one character)
- `\1` means it takes the first pattern it finds  (and only in this case) and uses it as replacement for the whole string